# Append dynamic javascript variable to HTML tag. InnerHTML & insertAdjacentHTML both incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of javascript variables that are being updated as an animation plays out.

What I'd like to do is append these to HTML elements but I'm having a few problems.  I can make it work by introducing a span tag into the HTML and targeting that instead but I'd like to know how I can do it without.

The code that currently works:

```
  <p id="infoCurrentDepth">Current Depth:<span id="bla"></span></p>

  var bla = $('bla');

  function updateInfoPanel(){

    bla.innerHTML = scaleControl.value;
}
```

I've removed code that isn't required.

What I'd like to do is just append the variable to to the p tag instead.  When I try this is repeats the value several times instead of replacing it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: try moving `var bla = $('bla');` to the `updateInfoPanel` method..

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: sure... also can you create a demo in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43172/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-steve-green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery there is no need to overwrite `$` to create a element selector. Use jQuery id selector along with manipulation methods like .html()/.append() like

So try the below after removing the `var $ = function(){...}`

```
$('#infoCurrentScale').append('sdfsdf');
```